# MySQL: Show list of tables with paging in Terminal

Tags: mysql-5.5, select

I am using MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44 for debian-linux-gnu.

How can I show my tables page wise in a terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the pager (see [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html)) command in MySQL console or use the --pager startup option ([docs again](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html)) to redirect the output of your commands to an external executable.

To use the pager command and list the tables try this:

```
mysql> pager less
mysql> show tables
```

You can also start MySQL to send all your output to an external executable like this

```
mysql --pager=/usr/bin/less
```

Comment: For completeness' sake, this can also be set in `~/.my.cnf` in the `[client]` section: `pager = /usr/bin/less`.

Answer (score 5):

You might also find the `tee` command to be of use.

Log all output to an operating system file `mytabs.txt`.

```
mysql> tee mytabs.txt;
Logging to file 'mytabs.txt'
```

Issue your `show tables` command as below.

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_sport |
+-----------------+
| billy           |
| player          |
| seasons         |
| team            |
+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Examine the contents of your file from within the mysql client. `\!` is the handy command for that.

```
mysql> \! more mytabs.txt;
mysql> show tables;        <<----- file contents
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_sport |
+-----------------+
| billy           |
| player          |
| seasons         |
| team            |
+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Turn of output logging.

```
mysql> notee;
Outfile disabled.
```

You can also examine the contents of the file via the shell - or alternatively, you could have your mysql client open and a shell terminal and switch between the two. Useful if you want permanent output to which you can refer later.

```
mysql> exit;
Bye
[pol@localhost inst]$ more mytabs.txt 
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_sport |
+-----------------+
| billy           |
| player          |
| seasons         |
| team            |
+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```